# Java remove multiple characters from string

Tags: java

I'm playing with string manipulation and I would like to do something like this, when a user types the lesson name: Windows Server, the program should remove Windows plus white space character and display only Server. I managed to do this using this code:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String lesson;

    System.out.println("Input lesson name: ");

    lesson = in.nextLine();

    String newLesson = lesson.replaceAll("Windows\\s+", "");

    System.out.println("New Lesson is " + newLesson);
```

But now I want to remove multiple characters like Linux and Unix. How would I include in my regex Linux and Unix?

If the user would type in Linux Administration, the program should display Administration only.

Comment: Do you have a defined list of words to remove? Do you always want to remove the first word?

Comment: So you just want to display the last word? Or just strip the first word? Pen down some test cases, and possible outcome for that, and from that, come to a definite rule. That would be better to deal with all inputs.

Comment: @assylias yes I want only to remove the first word

Comment: @RohitJain yes I want to just strip the first word with my defined list of words, Linux, Unix and Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question, try:

```
String newLesson = lesson.replaceAll("(Windows|Linux|Unix)\\s+", "");
```

**Output:**

```
Input lesson name: 
Linux Administration
Administration
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove only the first word your regex would `^\w+\s`

This says:

1. `^` match from the start of the string only
2. `\w+` Find 1 or more non-whitespace characters, do not be greedy so stop as soon as you find a match for
3. `\s` a whitespace character".

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here...

1. Create a Regex term that encompasses all the terms you want to remove, I *think* something like the below would do it (but I'm no  Regex expert).

   ```
   replaceAll("(Windows|Linux|Unix)\\s+", "");
   ```
2. Store the words you want to remove in a list then cycle through it, removing each term.

   ```
   List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList{"Windows\\s+", "Linux\\s+", "Unix\\s+"});

   for(String term : terms) {
       lesson = lesson.replaceAll(term, "");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to remove first word, and assuming that *space* is the delimiter, you can do it without regex:

```
String newLesson = lesson.substring(lesson.indexOf(" ") + 1);
```